# Help to analyze how a software/program constructs Bezier curve

Tags: c#, delphi, bezier

I am trying to understand how ChemDraw, a Industry-Leading Chemistry Tool developed by cambridgesoft, constructs Bezier curves, so that I can manually translate the Bezier curve points from other programs/routines (such as home-made Delphi/C# utilities) into the curve data recognizable for ChemDraw. Before starting, I must admit that I am asking how certain blackbox works internally, and therefore want to appologize for any trouble and appreciate any help!

I have made in ChemDraw four types of simplest Bezier curves and saved them as .CDXML file, the curve section of which have been pasted in the end. Both the .CDXML files and corresponding pictures can be downloaded from fileserve. [Download Bezier_curve_ChemDraw_sample here](http://www.fileserve.com/file/3Hm7xv8/bezier_curve.zip). [ChemDraw trial edition can be downloaded here](http://www.cambridgesoft.com/software/details/?fid=14&pid=236&tid=5561).

## Questions

Question 1. Take the curve points of the "Line" type for example, there are overall two points that I used when making this curve. Why does ChemDraw store six points for it? And how does ChemDraw interpret these points exactly? The same question exists for the other three types, which employs four explicit points at most.

Question 2. If the content of "Bezier curve using three points - first type" is displayed in ChemDraw, one can see the first point can not be (12.22, 104.25). I mean, its X coordinate is obviously larger than 12. Why is this happening? Does ChemDraw do some transformation with the data? The same question exists for "Bezier curve using four points".

Question 3. It seems the extra blank character at the end of the CurvePoints attribute makes difference. What is the difference exactly?

Could some one enlighten me about these problems?

## Curve sections in the ChemDraw .CDXML files

============ Line ==============
[image: Line]

```
 <curve  
 id="2"  
 Z="1"  
 ArrowheadType="Solid"  
 CurvePoints="143.47 116.25 143.47 116.25 143.47 116.25 300.22 117.75 300.22 117.75 300.22 117.75"  
 />
```

============ Bezier curve using three points - first type ==============
[image: Curve - three points - drag the starting point]

```
 <curve  
 id="2"  
 Z="1"  
 ArrowheadType="Solid"  
 CurvePoints="12.22 104.25 121.72 106.5 231.22 108.75 230.47 204 230.47 204 230.47 204"  
 />
```

============ Bezier curve using three points - second type ==============
[image: Curve - three points - drag the stopping point]

```
 <curve  
 id="2"  
 Z="1"  
 ArrowheadType="Solid"  
 CurvePoints="134.47 97.5 134.47 97.5 134.47 97.5 231.22 60.75 229.72 109.5 228.22 158.25"  
 />
```

============ Bezier curve using four points ==============
[image: Curve - three points - drag both the starting and the stopping points]

```
 <curve  
 id="2"  
 Z="1"  
 ArrowheadType="Solid"  
 CurvePoints="5.47 93.75 123.22 93.75 240.97 93.75 351.22 177.75 236.47 177.75 121.72 177.75"   
 />
```

## Example C# program to generate the same curves

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinForms_2_DrawBezier
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Text = "Draw Bezier Curve";
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            // DrawBezier_1(this, e);
            // DrawBezier_2(this, e);
            // DrawBezier_3(this, e);
             DrawBezier_4(this, e);
        }

        private void DrawBezier_1(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen l_pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            PointF l_pt1 = new PointF(143.47f, 116.25f);
            PointF l_pt2 = new PointF(l_pt1.X, l_pt1.Y);
            PointF l_pt3 = new PointF(l_pt1.X, l_pt1.Y);
            PointF l_pt4 = new PointF(300.22f, 117.75f);
            PointF l_pt5 = new PointF(l_pt4.X, l_pt4.Y);
            PointF l_pt6 = new PointF(l_pt4.X, l_pt4.Y);

            PointF[] l_pts = new PointF[6];
            l_pts[0] = l_pt1;
            l_pts[1] = l_pt2;
            l_pts[2] = l_pt3;
            l_pts[3] = l_pt4;
            l_pts[4] = l_pt5;
            l_pts[5] = l_pt6;

            // e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt2, l_pt5, l_pt6);

            e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt3, l_pt4, l_pt6); // As suggested by Dani

            // e.Graphics.DrawBeziers(l_pen, l_pts);
        }

        private void DrawBezier_2(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen l_pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            PointF l_pt1 = new PointF(12.22f, 104.25f);
            PointF l_pt2 = new PointF(121.72f, 106.5f);
            PointF l_pt3 = new PointF(231.22f, 108.75f);
            PointF l_pt4 = new PointF(230.47f, 204f);
            PointF l_pt5 = new PointF(l_pt4.X, l_pt4.Y);
            PointF l_pt6 = new PointF(l_pt4.X, l_pt4.Y);

            PointF[] l_pts = new PointF[6];
            l_pts[0] = l_pt1;
            l_pts[1] = l_pt2;
            l_pts[2] = l_pt3;
            l_pts[3] = l_pt4;
            l_pts[4] = l_pt5;
            l_pts[5] = l_pt6;

            // e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt2, l_pt3, l_pt4);

            e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt3, l_pt4, l_pt6); // As suggested by Dani

            // e.Graphics.DrawBeziers(l_pen, l_pts);
        }

        private void DrawBezier_3(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen l_pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            PointF l_pt1 = new PointF(134.47f, 97.5f);
            PointF l_pt2 = new PointF(l_pt1.X, l_pt1.Y);
            PointF l_pt3 = new PointF(l_pt1.X, l_pt1.Y);
            PointF l_pt4 = new PointF(231.22f, 60.75f);
            PointF l_pt5 = new PointF(229.72f, 109.5f);
            PointF l_pt6 = new PointF(228.22f, 158.25f);

            PointF[] l_pts = new PointF[6];
            l_pts[0] = l_pt1;
            l_pts[1] = l_pt2;
            l_pts[2] = l_pt3;
            l_pts[3] = l_pt4;
            l_pts[4] = l_pt5;
            l_pts[5] = l_pt6;

            // e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt3, l_pt4, l_pt5, l_pt6);

            e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt3, l_pt4, l_pt6); // As suggested by Dani

            // e.Graphics.DrawBeziers(l_pen, l_pts);
        }

        private void DrawBezier_4(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Pen l_pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            PointF l_pt1 = new PointF(5.47f, 93.75f);
            PointF l_pt2 = new PointF(123.22f, 93.75f);
            PointF l_pt3 = new PointF(240.97f, 93.75f);
            PointF l_pt4 = new PointF(351.22f, 177.75f);
            PointF l_pt5 = new PointF(236.47f, 177.75f);
            PointF l_pt6 = new PointF(121.72f, 177.75f);

            PointF[] l_pts = new PointF[6];
            l_pts[0] = l_pt1;
            l_pts[1] = l_pt2;
            l_pts[2] = l_pt3;
            l_pts[3] = l_pt4;
            l_pts[4] = l_pt5;
            l_pts[5] = l_pt6;

            // e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt4, l_pt5, l_pt6);

            e.Graphics.DrawBezier(l_pen, l_pt1, l_pt3, l_pt4, l_pt6); // As suggested by Dani

            // e.Graphics.DrawBeziers(l_pen, l_pts);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I cannot make this C# utility generate the same curves as ChemDraw displays except for the first `Line` type.
[image: C# DrawBezier_1 screen-capture]
[image: C# DrawBezier_2 screen-capture]
[image: C# DrawBezier_3 screen-capture]
[image: C# DrawBezier_4 screen-capture]

Comment: Upvoted because of the detailed question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its using the standard bezier curve algorithm which can take any amount of points to construct a curve. look at [Bézier curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)

Edit:
C# DrawBezier only supports quadratic (four points) bezier. You four point bezier will be translated to C# using:

```
float[] CurvePoints = GetCurvePoints();

DrawBezier(Pen, CurvePoints[0], CurvePoints[1], CurvePoints[4], CurvePoints[5],
                CurvePoints[6], CurvePoints[7], CurvePoints[10], CurvePoints[11]);
```

Where `GetCurvePoints()` just gives you the list of points from `CurvePoints` xml attribute.

Edit 2:
Code to reproduce <strike>the last curve</strike> **all** curves:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Bezier : Form
{
    static public void Main ()
    {
        Application.Run (new Bezier ());
    }

    protected override void OnPaint (PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // The input with all points
        string CurveDataString = "5.47 93.75 123.22 93.75 240.97 93.75 351.22 177.75 236.47 177.75 121.72 177.75";

        string[] CurveDataStringParts = CurveDataString.Split(' ');

        int[] Keep = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
        float[] CurveData = (from i in Keep select float.Parse(CurveDataStringParts[i])).ToArray();

        e.Graphics.DrawBezier(Pens.Black, CurveData[0], CurveData[1], CurveData[2], CurveData[3],
                                          CurveData[4], CurveData[5], CurveData[6], CurveData[7]);

        for(int i = 0; i < CurveData.Length; i += 2)
        {
            e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.Black, new RectangleF(CurveData[i] - 2, CurveData[i + 1] - 2, 4, 4));
        }

        base.OnPaint (e);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Bezier example]

Comment: Thank you for your comments very much! Are you referreing to "Degree elevation"? Also, could you help to comment a little bit further about how to transform in practice the points used in, for example, the C# function Graphics.DrawBezier/DrawBeziers to/from the points used in the ChemDraw mentioned above?

Comment: Thank you for your elaboration! Do you mean if I let `GetCurvePoints` return the data contained in the ChemDraw CurvePoints xml attribute, C# Graphics.DrawBezier will generate the same curve as displayed by ChemDraw? I am sorry but (1) the ChemDraw CurvePoints xml attribute contains six points for the four examples posted above, (2) `DrawBezier` accept four points and (3) `DrawBeziers` seem to accept 4+3n points. PS: I tried to supply `DrawBeziers` with those six points and could not get the same or even valid picture. Could you help to comment?

Comment: @Xichen Li: I'm sorry, two points need to be discarded there. I will update my post. `DrawBeziers` just draws few beziers, not higher/lower order bezier so it wont help for the other beziers.

Comment: Thanks for your time! It seems you have kept the first, the third, the fourth, and the sixth points out of the six points (concerning the four examples posted above). I am sorry but I just tried for the four examples and DrawBezier does not generate the same as ChemDraw displays except for the `Line` example. Is there something that I possibly did wrong? Are there some rules regarding which points to discard?

Comment: @Xichen Li: I have tried it myself and it works, I will soon post full source code for it.

Comment: Great to hear it works! Then I must have not understood your suggestions! (I have also posted the source code that I used in the original post, together with the screen captures.)

Comment: @Xichen Li: Actually, it uses order 6 curve (hence 6 points). you will have to use a library to draw arbitrary order curves. You can use this one: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BezirCurves.aspx, it looks simple. just pass all points to it.

Comment: @Xichen Li: I managed to obtain a exact duplicate on the last curve by discarding first and last point. looks like it stores them with no reason, I'll add the code in an edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion! It does work for all the four curves posted above! What's more, your coding style is also refreshing!

Comment: With your help, the reason why the extra TWO points exist seems clear: For each anchor point, ChemDraw stores it, and its symmetric one. Thus, there are TWO extra anchor points: one for the starting one, and the other for the stopping one. In this respect, transforming data from C# into ChemDraw CurvePoints should necessitate calculation and addition of these TWO anchor points, and transforming from ChemDraw into C# should involve deletion of these TWO redundant anchor points. Thanks for your precious time and kind help again! :)